# how to configure body mapping template for AWS gateway API which take string as input

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm using AWS API gateway to create a post rest API. The rest API will add data in the dynamoDB table "Metadata" which has four columns.

The input to the rest API is a string like "2 -164 4104 1.50", where each space-separated value belongs to the "Metadata" table columns value in sequence order.

I'm unable to figure out how I can configure the Body Mapping Templates which can parse the input string and map it to table column in sequence order.

The required output is shown in below image:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2fpF.png

I tried to split the string, splitting is fine. But I'm getting Response as 
  "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"

My mapping is content-type: application/json:

```
 #set($rawAPIData=$inout.path('$'))
    #set($s=$rawAPIData.split(""))
    "TableName": "Metadata",
    "Item": {
    "id": {
            "S": "$s.get(0)"
    },
    "cap": {
            "S": "$s.get(1)"
    },
    "counter": {
            "S": "$s.get(2)"
    },
    "timer": {
            "S": "$s.get(3)"
    }
    }
```

Output logs:
Endpoint request body after transformations:

"TableName": "Metadata",
"Item": {
    "id": {
        "S": "2"
},
"cap": {
        "S": "-164"
},
"counter": {
        "S": "4104"
},
"timer": {
        "S": "1.50"
}
}

Endpoint response headers: {Server=Server, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=J89RJ8GPC2D95GT0AP284PQSPBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, x-amz-crc32=3948637019, Content-Length=60, Date=Sun, 26 Nov 2017 07:08:49 GMT, Content-Type=application/x-amz-json-1.0}
Method response body after transformations: {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"}

Seems the problem is with using application/json as content type and providing input as a string. How can I solve this use case?
Help is much appreciated.

Comment: You *should* be able to use the `.indexOf()` and `.substring()` methods and some intermediate variables to carve up your string into substrings that you could then map into place... or maybe even make an array with `.split(' ')`.  You might give one of those a try and come back with some code edited into your question, if you get stuck.  I have used VTL very little but this is what I would be inclined to try.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have added the error I'm facing now. Could you please have a look once again.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in body mapping template? You can do it in front-end or in lambda.

Comment: You took my suggestion and ran with it.  Nice work.  You appear to have overlooked the need for an opening `{` in your request body... you need `{ "TableName": ...`.

Comment: @DmitryGrinko true, but you can do quite a lot with mapping templates if you get a little bit creative, and eliminate the additonal latency and cost of invoking a Lambda function.

Comment: Thanks! The issue is resolved by adding the missing opening in the request body. And the plain text is supported with content-type "application/json".